# How to setup web application created in PHP (with Xampp)?

Tags: php, web-applications, installation, xampp, localhost

I have created an administrative system for libraries which basically lets you register books, users, borrowings and all kind of stuff that happens in a library. To code and test it, I used XAMPP, in my own PC, using Apache PHP and MySQL to structure and develop the application.

It works, and has a very complete and efficient set of functions and utilities, that is why I plan to implement it in my school's library, that for years has been using Microsoft Excel as a tool to organize all the books and students.

The thing is: I don't understand how to setup this app as a local web application. The idea is to install the folders and files in the library computer so it can control the system locally and through a browser (using localhost to access the PHP application).

I know it is possible to simply install XAMPP manually and copy the folder to htdocs and then use it normally, but I want to eliminate the *manual* part, and have some sort of setup that lets any person install the app without having to understand how Apache or MySQL works.

**Does anybody know what could I do?** I have though of creating a series of batch files (the library PC uses Windows) and move folders, create shortcuts, etc. using normal cmd commands. It would be a better alternative, but still the user would need to go through XAMPP (or some other service) setup prompts.

Thanks very much

Comment: https://www.easyphp.org/ - this software is easiest way to setup PHP+Mysql+Apache environment in windows as I know. Install, start, import DB, place files to web root. Mostly works started via task scheduler on boot.

Comment: Using uWamp server we can bundle php project with mysql and distribute it easily. [Check this](http://www.uwamp.com/en/)

Answer (score 0):

you can create a bash file to automate this process.